# Open parent app from ShieldAction extension in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Using the ScreenTime API I have an app shielded with 2 button actions: one to remove the shield and open the app as normal, and the other to keep the app shielded and open the parent app instead.

Is there any way to open the parent app from the extension?

```
 class ShieldActionExtension: ShieldActionDelegate {
   override func handle(action: ShieldAction, for application: ApplicationToken, completionHandler: @escaping (ShieldActionResponse) -> Void) {
    // Handle the action as needed.
    
    let store = ManagedSettingsStore()
            
    switch action {
    case .primaryButtonPressed:
        //open parent app
        
        completionHandler(.defer)
    case .secondaryButtonPressed:
        //remove shield
        store.shield.applications?.remove(application)
        completionHandler(.defer)


    @unknown default:
        fatalError()
    }
    
   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do this via the API as of now.

One workaround which I used was to set a threshold of 0 seconds for a ManagedSettings shield. Then, right when the application is opened, the threshold is reached and the delegate method of a DeviceActivityMonitorExtension will be called. In that delegate method you can create and immediately deliver a local notification.

The user will receive the local notification as a banner and can then click on it to enter your app.

This would require the user to 1) enable notifications for your app and 2) not presently be in silenced mode.

Comment: nice work around. Unfortunately needed. But a good plan b